# iOS - Playing Tock sound for custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, keyboard

I am trying to play the Tock sound for my custom keyboard.

What I have tried:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
```

and

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.UIKit"] pathForResource:@"Tock" ofType:@"aiff"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
```

and

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450);
```

and

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType: @"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath ];
myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
[myAudioPlayer play];
```

This gave me an ERROR:

```
AudioSessionClient: Couldn't connect to com.apple.audio.AudioSession
Couldn't connect to com.apple.audio.AudioQueueServer; AudioQueue will not be usable
```

and also looked into this [link](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary)

When I tried these codes in my ViewControllers (not the custom keyboard) it all worked. But when I tested it on my custom keyboard it idled for at least 10 seconds and I couldn't hear anything.

I also made sure that my iPhone is not on silent mode, speaker is not broken, keyboard clicks is enabled. I tested these codes on my iPhone and iPad and it turned out the same

Xcode Version 6.3.1 
iOS Version 8.3

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

In the Info.plist.

```
RequestsOpenAccess = YES
```

and with this code on my `KeyboardViewController.m`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `<UIInputViewAudioFeedback>` protocol on your ***input view***. I.e. you have a keyboard (`UIView` subclass) which has buttons on it, which implements this code:
- `.h` file:

```
@interface RHTableKeyboard : UIView <UIInputViewAudioFeedback>

@end
```

`.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)enableInputClicksWhenVisible
{
    return YES;
}
```

Then you might subclass `UIButton` and do something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (highlightColour) {
        origionalColour = self.backgroundColor;
        [self.layer setBackgroundColor:[highlightColour CGColor]];
    }
    if (makeClickSound) {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] playInputClick];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    if (highlightColour) {
        [self.layer setBackgroundColor:[origionalColour CGColor]];
    }
}
```

(I chucked in the code to make it change color as a bonus.)